# Check If IPv4/IPv6 Address is up using PHP

Tags: php, linux, ping, ipv6, ipv4

I have an IPv4 address. Ex. `172.19.20.21`

I used to do this

```
$fs = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,3);
if( !$fs ){
  $error = 'SSC is down';
  return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', $error )
  ->withInput(Request::except('password'));
}
```

It works perfectly fine.

Now, I have an IPv6  Address Ex. `3000::1`

```
if ((strpos($ip, ":") > -1)){

     // Code for IPv6 check
    $fs = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,3);
    if( !$fs ){
      $error = 'SSC is down';
      return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', $error )
      ->withInput(Request::except('password'));
    }

}else{

    // Code for IPv4 check
    $fs = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,3);
    if( !$fs ){
      $error = 'SSC is down';
      return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', $error )
      ->withInput(Request::except('password'));
    }
}
```

Can I use this code above ? Or I need to look for other solution for IPv6 ?

Comment: This will only differentiate between v4 and v6 if you are 100% certain that what you got in`$ip_address` is an IP. If that's ok with you then this should work.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` blocks are identical, so you're basically saying "if I don't change my code, will it work for IPv6?" To which my response is, "have you tried it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin way to parse an IP address is [inet_pton()](http://php.net/inet_pton):

> This function converts a human readable IPv4 or IPv6 address (if PHP
>   was built with IPv6 support enabled) into an address family
>   appropriate 32bit or 128bit binary structure.

To determine the format you can, for instance, count the resulting bytes:

```
strlen(inet_pton($ip))
```

```
4 bytes = 32 bits = IPv4
16 bytes = 128 bits = IPv6
```

(In your precise use case, though, it's kind of unclear why you need this in the first place.)