# pinging ipv6 in PHP

Tags: php, websocket, ping, ipv6

I'm trying to ping (Send ICMP Echo Request package) ipv6 address using methods from:  [How can I ping a server port with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841635/how-can-i-ping-a-server-port-with-php) with fsockopen and socket. This methods works only with ipv4. Is it possible to use this in v6 mode?

Comment: This issue has already been discussed in following title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298670/check-if-ipv4-ipv6-address-is-up-using-php

Comment: This is not pinging on ipv6. Just only opening socket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check If IPv4/IPv6 Address is up using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298670/check-if-ipv4-ipv6-address-is-up-using-php)

Comment: No, this is the same link from comment nr 1